# How do I use tent mode with an Acer Spin 5?

Tags: laptop, acer, tablet

I just got an Acer Spin 5 and so far the laptop mostly works out of the box with XUbuntu, including pen sensitivity. However I do not know how to get tent mode to work. Can anyone give me any pointers? Thank you.

Model :Acer Spin 5 SP513-52N

Comment: you are lucky having touchscreen and pen working :/ on a newer model (Spin 5 SP513-54N), none of it is working - and not even the touchpad https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251719/ubuntu-20-04-acer-spin-5-sp513-54n-touchpad-and-touchscreen-stylus-pen-not-wor